# sed command to replace the Sting to DD-MMM-YYYY date format in a record

Tags: linux, date, sed, format

I am trying to reprint the entire record `06/08/2023 06:30:11 06/08/2023 06:30:19` while replacing the string `06/08/2023` which is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format to `DD-MMM-YYYY` format i.e, `08-JUN-2023`

I have almost got it. but the instead of printing `08-JUN-2023` it's printing the date `01-Feb-0003`

```
echo "06/08/2023 06:30:11 06/08/2023 06:30:19" | sed -E 's#([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})#'"$(echo '\2/\1/\3' | xargs -I{} date -d {} +'%d-%^b-%Y')"#g
```

everything was working when tested individually. but now this command is giving the below result where the date is wrong `01-Feb-0003 06:30:11 01-Feb-0003 06:30:19`

i was researching about `sed` and `date` commands, could some one throw light on it and provide the correct solution for this?

Comment: `$()` gets evaluated before your sed command runs

Comment: Hi @Sundeep thankyou for the response. as the $() is evaluted first,  i am trying this echo "06/08/2023 06:30:11 06/08/2023 06:30:19" | sed -E 's#([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})#'"$(awk -F'[/]' '{print $1"/"$2"/"$3}' | xargs -I{} date -d {} +'%d-%^b-%Y')"#g now. getting date: invalid date ‘06/08/2023 06:30:11 06’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ echo "06/08/2023 06:30:11 06/08/2023 06:30:19" | sed -E "s#[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+#echo \$(date -d '&' +'%d-%^h-%Y')#g;s/echo //2ge"
08-JUN-2023 06:30:11 08-JUN-2023 06:30:19
```

Comment: Hello @HatLess thanks for the response. Here is a little extension. echo "a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 06/09/2023 06:30:30 06/09/2023 06:32:45 SU 307404729/1 0" |sed -E "s#([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})#echo \$(date -d '&' +'%d-%^h-%Y')#g;s/echo //2ge" without the  first field (a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh), everything working as expected. but with the first field, getting sh: a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh: command not found

Comment: @Mahesh Try `echo "a_0001_hst_script5v00.sh 06/09/2023 06:30:30 06/09/2023 06:32:45 SU 307404729/1 0" |sed -E "s#([^/]*)?([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})#echo \1\$(date -d '\\2' +'%d-%^h-%Y')#g;s/echo //2ge"`

Answer (score 2):

I'd reach for perl so you can do everything in one tool

```bash
echo "06/08/2023 06:30:11 06/08/2023 06:30:19" \
| perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
    s{\b(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\b}
     { Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%m/%d/%Y")->strftime("%d-%^b-%Y") }ge
  '
```

```
08-JUN-2023 06:30:11 08-JUN-2023 06:30:19
```

I would also encourage you to use the [unambiguous `YYYY-mm-dd` date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates).

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk and without having to call an external tool like `date` for every input line (which would be extremely slow):

```
$ echo '06/08/2023 06:30:11 06/08/2023 06:30:19' |
awk '{
    split($1,a,"/")
    $1 = a[2] "-" substr("JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC",a[1]*3-2,3) "-" a[3]
}1'
08-JUN-2023 06:30:11 06/08/2023 06:30:19
```

As @GlennJackman said: I would also encourage you to use the [unambiguous `YYYY-mm-dd` date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates).